# Return False & Javascript Form

Tags: javascript

I've looked over a number of posts that are similar to my query, but in general, they are not helping me.  I think part of my problem is that I am so new to JavaScript that a lot of the previous posts are too complicated for me.  I have the simple code below, but it does not seem to work.  I do not get my alerts, and I do not think the form is being submitted even when the function should be returning "true."  I checked the Error Console, and there are no errors.  Can someone help?

**JavaScript:**

```
function submit()
{

var age = document.Message.Age.value;

if (age > 39)
{
    alert("You're old.");
    return false;
}

else
{
    alert("You're young!");
    return true;
}

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<FORM id = "Message" name = "Message" method = "post" action = "http://cnn.com" onsubmit = "return submit();">

First Name: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Fname"/><br>
Age: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Age"/><br>
<INPUT type="button" name = "Submit" value = "Submit">


</FORM>
```

Comment: Weird, I don't know why the HTML above didn't display everything I input.  In any event, here is the HTML:  <FORM id = "Message" name = "Message" method = "post" action = "http://cnn.com" onsubmit = "return submit();">

First Name: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Fname"/><br>
Age: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Age"/><br>
<INPUT type="button" name = "Submit" value = "Submit">


</FORM>

Comment: You'll need to read the [editing-help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for guidance on how to use the Markdown editor. And *don't* post chunks of html in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: When I refresh the page, I see the HTML.  So I guess it's OK...?

Comment: That's because we edited it to help. Please: read the guidance, it'll make your future questions to, and use of, the site more pleasant. Not to mention far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to

```
<FORM id = "Message" name = "Message" method = "post" action = "http://cnn.com" onsubmit = "return submit();">

First Name: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Fname"/><br>
Age: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Age"/><br>
<INPUT type="submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit">


</FORM>
```

Note that the input type has been changed to 'submit', so that the submission actually takes place.

Comment: I'm still not getting my alerts, though.  Is something wrong with the JavaScript itself?  It seems crazy simple... I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

**I doubt your javascript function itself is being called or not.** If not, I think you need to move you `onsubmit` to `<body>` tag from `<form>` tag.
as

```
 <body onsubmit"return submit();">
```

Also either change your button to either type as `submit` or add an `onClick()` event below:

```
 <INPUT type="submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit"/>
```

or

```
 <INPUT type="button" name = "Submit" value = "Submit" onClick="submit()"/>
```

Below is the full working code(in chrome and IE8) sample:

```
<Html>
 <head>
   <script language="javascript">
   function submit(){
     var age = document.Message.Age.value;
     if (age > 39){
        alert("You're old.");
        return false;
     }else{
        alert("You're young!");
        return true;
     }
   } 
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <FORM id = "Message" name = "Message" method = "post" 
               action = "http://cnn.com" onSubmit = "javascript:return submit();">
    First Name: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Fname"/><br>
    Age: <INPUT type = "text" name = "Age"/><br>
    <INPUT type="submit" name = "Submit" value = "Submit"/>
   </FORM>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onsubmit` only applies to FORM tags [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3)

Comment: @Dancrumb:  I was thinking the same but it doesn't work in Chrome and IE8(I tried in these two). At least with me. While `body` event is working fine. I also added one line message in the beginning to share my view little more clear.

Comment: @user1761975: Did you try moving the method as I suggested?

Comment: I added the "body onsubmit" as suggested, and changed the button to add the onClick, and I still don't get my alerts.  So bizarre.  I'm pretty close to giving up.  It's a practice exercise for class (in other words, it's not even graded), and I'm not sure it's worth the frustration.

Comment: @user1761975 I updated the answer with my full test code. Please try. If still doesn't work, please make sure, script execution is enabled in  your browser. You can simply try that by putting `onclick=alert();` in you button and verifying alert is coming or not.